# How Do You Databind Avalon DateTimePicker Start Value?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datetime

Trying to set the start time of the Avalon DateTimePicker, but all I get is the current time.
Anyone had any success with this control.  FYI, I am stuck using .Net 3.0.

```
  <wf:DateTimePicker x:Name="DatePickerStartTime"                                           
      DateTimeSelected="{Binding Path=StartTime,Mode=TwoWay}" >                                        
 </wf:DateTimePicker>
```

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

The control defaulted to local time on load.  I set the StartTime after it loaded and the binding worked.